# What is the difference between copy and move in restoring database?

Tags: odoo

The *Restore Database* window states that:

> **This database might have been moved or copied.**
>
> In order to avoid conflicts between databases, Odoo needs to know if this database was moved or copied. If you don't know, answer "This database is a copy".

While it makes sense that there is a difference, it is not clear what exactly. In what case should one use copy and in what move?

Odoo version: 9.0c

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/tag/9-0c-6642/questions

Comment: @Moab I don't see how that can help. There is no question about that...

Comment: How are you restoring the DB with written logic syntax or some GUI app? Is this connecting to an app DB on a machine or a SQL Server DB, or some other DB with another technology?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT question is Odoo GUI specific. One acces that particular window by pushing the **Restore Database** button at `.../web/database/manager`

Comment: @ruuter then ask your own question on that forum, there are bound to be more experts for that software over there.

Comment: @Moab So what you are saying is, that this here is not a place for such a question? Sorry if I have misunderstood the point of superuser.

Comment: Not at all, just saying you may have better luck over there.

Comment: @Moab Ok then thank you, but part of the reason of asking this here was to create content to stackexchange ;)

Comment: The odoo forum is very buggy, esp. in regards to karma so stackexchange is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The following code can be found under `"/odoo/odoo/service/db.py:286".`
>   As I see it, the only difference is that with a copy a new database
>   uid is created and with a move the old uid remains.

```
 if copy:
     # if it's a copy of a database, force generation of a new dbuuid
     env['ir.config_parameter'].init(force=True)
```

--Mathias Markl

> This has implications for licensing in the case of the Enterprise
>   Edition - a license is assigned (linked) to a DBUUID (but can be
>   re-linked).

--Ray Carnes

Comment: Ok, accepting your answer. The enterprise quote is good to know. Alltho I would add `odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_config_parameter.py:40` where you can see that init with `force=true` will also overwrite default parameters: db.secret, db.create_date and web.base.url. So addition to `uuid` move will also keep those, while copy sets those to default.